# Как сделать прокрутку данных в диалоговом окне в виде колесика?

Tags: java, android

Только начал изучать android. В своей программе хочу использовать диалоговое окно такого плана, как ниже. Очень похоже, что это AlertDialog, но не могу понять как отобразить такое колесо прокрутки. Это какой-то стандартный виджет? Знающие люди, направьте, пожалуйста, в нужную сторону.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это стандартный компонент под названием [NumberPicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html).

> Компонент NumberPicker из раздела Expert позволяет выбрать нужное число из заданного диапазона. Принцип работы похож на револьверный барабан - можно прокручивать числа в одну или другую сторону. Когда будет достигнут заданный предел, то числа продолжат изменяться в заданном диапазоне.

[Вот](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/numberpicker.php) краткое описание этого компонента и как его использовать.

А если хотите использовать диалог с этим компонентом, вот вам пример реализации: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17806895/2506123

**Код с примера:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener
{
    private static TextView tv;
    static Dialog d ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
         b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 show();
            }
            });
           }
     @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

         Log.i("value is",""+newVal);

     }

    public void show()
    {

         final Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
         d.setTitle("NumberPicker");
         d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
         Button b1 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
         Button b2 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button2);
         final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
         np.setMaxValue(100);
         np.setMinValue(0);
         np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
         np.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
         b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              tv.setText(String.valueOf(np.getValue()));
              d.dismiss();
           }    
          });
         b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              d.dismiss();
           }    
          });
       d.show();


    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Open" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

dialog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:text="Cancel" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:text="Set" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

res/values/dimens.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! NumberPicker именно то, что я искал)